# import script for CSV to PostgreSQL *Updated*

Tags: postgresql, csv, clojure, import-csv

I am trying to create a simple script that imports old records to a new PostgreSQL database using the same Schema as the old one.

My initial idea was to read the contents of the `.csv` and create a *map* data structure. After that, insert it to the newly created database, using something like [Honey SQL](https://github.com/seancorfield/honeysql). Hopefully that makes sense.

I might be doing something wrong, or I probably am overthinking something here.

Let's say I have a script with the following functions:

```
(defn csv-data->map
  "Takes the data from the csv file and
   and stores it in a map structure."
  [csv-data]
  (map zipmap
       (->> (first csv-data)
            (map keyword)
            repeat)
       (rest csv-data)))

;; the map structure
(def big-map (with-open [reader (io/reader "my-file.csv")]
               (doall
                (csv-data->map (csv/read-csv reader)))))
```

So, I want to get the information stored in this map structure and import it in a PostgreSQL database.

Is there a way I can do that?

Also, here are the dependencies I am using, which are mostly from the official documentation for each lib.

```
(:require [clojure.data.csv :as csv]
          [clojure.java.io :as io]
          [next.jdbc :as jdbc]
          [honey.sql :as sql]
          [honey.sql.helpers :refer [select select-distinct from
                                     join left-join right-join
                                     where for group-by having union
                                     order-by limit offset values columns
                                     update insert-into set composite
                                     delete delete-from truncate] :as h]
          [clojure.core :as c])
```

It'll be great to see your critique and proposals!

My honey code is fairly simple:

```
(-> (h/insert-into :account)
    (h/values [big-map])
    (sql/format {:pretty true}))
```

The **error** message I get when trying to evaluate in the REPL is this

> Unhandled clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo
> These SQL clauses are unknown or have nil values: :ID,
> :BILLINGLONGITUDE... etc

and under it, I get the real objects like so:

> {:ID "000123456000000",
> :BILLINGLONGITUDE "",... etc

Adding a little update on the problem:
So I am connected to the PG database and I can perform a simple query to get some count from a table account, but I get the following problem:

> 1. Unhandled org.postgresql.util.PSQLException    ERROR: relation "account" does not exist Position: 13
>
>    QueryExecutorImpl.java: 2477  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl/receiveErrorResponse
>    QueryExecutorImpl.java: 2190  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl/processResults
>    QueryExecutorImpl.java:  300  org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl/execute
>    PgStatement.java:  428  org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement/executeInternal
>    PgStatement.java:  354  org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement/execute   PgPreparedStatement.java:
>    169  org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement/executeWithFlags
>    PgPreparedStatement.java:  158
>    org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement/execute
>    result_set.clj:  669  next.jdbc.result-set/stmt->result-set
>    result_set.clj:  664  next.jdbc.result-set/stmt->result-set
>    result_set.clj:  944  next.jdbc.result-set/eval9989/fn
>    protocols.clj:   34  next.jdbc.protocols/eval9066/fn/G
>    result_set.clj: 1023  next.jdbc.result-set/eval10028/fn
>    protocols.clj:   34  next.jdbc.protocols/eval9066/fn/G
>    jdbc.clj:  250  next.jdbc/execute!
>    jdbc.clj:  237  next.jdbc/execute!
>    REPL:   43  csv-lein.core/eval11779
>    REPL:   43  csv-lein.core/eval11779
>    Compiler.java: 7194  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
>    Compiler.java: 7149  clojure.lang.Compiler/eval
>    core.clj: 3215  clojure.core/eval
>    core.clj: 3211  clojure.core/eval
>    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn/fn
>    AFn.java:  152  clojure.lang.AFn/applyToHelper
>    AFn.java:  144  clojure.lang.AFn/applyTo
>    core.clj:  667  clojure.core/apply
>    core.clj: 1990  clojure.core/with-bindings*
>    core.clj: 1990  clojure.core/with-bindings*
>    RestFn.java:  425  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
>    interruptible_eval.clj:   87  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate/fn
>    main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print/fn
>    main.clj:  437  clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print
>    main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl/fn
>    main.clj:  458  clojure.main/repl
>    main.clj:  368  clojure.main/repl
>    RestFn.java: 1523  clojure.lang.RestFn/invoke
>    interruptible_eval.clj:   84  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
>    interruptible_eval.clj:   56  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
>    interruptible_eval.clj:  152  nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval/fn/fn
>    AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
>    session.clj:  218  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop/fn
>    session.clj:  217  nrepl.middleware.session/session-exec/main-loop
>    AFn.java:   22  clojure.lang.AFn/run
>    Thread.java:  833  java.lang.Thread/run

Comment: So what problem are you facing? Please add the error/stacktrace/... you are facing.

Comment: I don't see any code using jdbc or honey?

Comment: I don't really know how else to send my big-map structure to the database